# Ensemble method, what should I do?

Tags: python-3.x, ensemble-learning

Please, why is estimators function in Ensemble learning not working in python 3?

```
StackingClassifier(estimators=base_learners, final_estimator=LogisticRegression())

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'estimators'
```

That is the error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide the code you're using ?

Comment: It's clear you've got a keyword argument which isn't expected, but there's no helping without more context

Answer (score 0):

Since you are receiving a TypeError, you are probably passing incorrect data type to the function. Assuming that you are using sklearn.ensemble.StackingClassifier ([docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.StackingClassifier.html)), it requires a list of (str, estimator) tuples.